# report builder - how to use an if statement?

Tags: if-statement

I have been watching some report builder tutorials but can't find one on how to use controls, particularly for this code?

=iif(CountRows("ConfinedSpacePermit_280")>0,False,True)

I have got some kind of an error message about being an integer...

Comment: What error message you get? Not easy to help this way.

Comment: Are you setting a parameter? If so then perhaps it is not a boolean datatype.